# Showing a view that should be able to swipe over another fixed view

Tags: android

I have a fixed view in layout now I want a map view that should be partially visible at initial and when we swipe it to right it should appear on the full screen but another view should be fixed at a place.

for more please refer screenshots :
Please help me out and suggest me some solution for this

[image]

[image]

Comment: You will have to create a custom view with this and implement a ViewDragHelper.

Comment: would you help me out in this with some example?